# Why does launching iOS Xcode simulator create Crash Report after MacOS Catalina upgrade, and what to do about it?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

Recently upgraded my Macbook to Catalina OS v10.15.1 and have since been experiencing performance problems with the Simulator in Xcode (11.2.1).

To be precise, the simulator is working OK, but my Macbook fan starts running high immediately after launching the simulator, then the laptop starts to get very warm. This follows up with a Crash Report from process **searchd** (below). The process **Launchd_sim** is also taking lots of CPU processing according to Activity Monitor (also below).

Strangely, the simulator works fine but the Macbook fan is running abnormally high and is very hot. I did not have this problem prior to going to Catalina OS.

When quitting the simulator, the fan slows to normal speed and the machine seems to cool down. This situation is repeatable.  Anyone else seen this problem?

Simulator version is 11.2.1 (SimulatorApp-912.4 SimulatorKit-570.3 CoreSimulator-681.15).

From Console's Crash Report:

```
Process:               searchd [11382]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Search.framework/searchd
Identifier:            searchd
Version:               2073.1
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [11219]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [1176]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-12-15 10:37:31.277 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        19B5ACA8-D061-41E2-1CD0-65EBEB8D3499

Sleep/Wake UUID:       44265181-901D-4D25-AF95-C778F4B5F151

Time Awake Since Boot: 30000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.metadata.spotlightindex.Flush scheduler for index at /Users/jeffs_itunes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4B8D

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000200000010
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [11382]

VM Regions Near 0x200000010:
    __LINKEDIT             000000010d769000-000000010d7a1000 [  224K] r--/r-- SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> 
    STACK GUARD            0000700006f23000-0000700006f24000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 1

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 681.15 - Device: iPhone 8 (4B8DA2C2-A685-4076-8B21-3FF303DDEFC5) - Runtime: iOS 13.2 (17B102) - DeviceType: iPhone 8

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b54166 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b546cc mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff23bb1aa5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 197
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff23bac7c7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1671
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff23babe16 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff2574b87f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 211
6   searchd                         0x000000010169ed5a 0x101692000 + 52570
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff51a1dc25 start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.metadata.spotlightindex.Flush scheduler for index at /Users/jeffs_itunes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4B8D
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff51bf6732 _platform_strlen + 18
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff51ac73f2 strdup + 18
2   com.apple.spotlight.SpotlightDaemon 0x00007fff44086956 SDTransactionDone + 17
3   com.apple.spotlight.SpotlightDaemon 0x00007fff4405c964 syncFinished + 36
4   com.apple.mobilespotlight.index 0x00007fff3c8c4ed9 delayed_op_final + 15
5   com.apple.mobilespotlight.index 0x00007fff3c8bd05f flush_runLoop + 105
6   com.apple.mobilespotlight.index 0x00007fff3c910547 work_fun + 634
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519eb265 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519de7b9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4526 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4f93 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 443
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4394 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 305
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4f93 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 443
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e5e90 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 992
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519eeff9 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0171b _pthread_wqthread + 290
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0157b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.searchd.createEncryptedRankingBackupQueue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b56a16 __ulock_wait + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519defb4 _dlock_wait + 44
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519df23f _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 43
3   searchd                         0x00000001016adeb8 0x101692000 + 114360
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519dd848 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519de7b9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e466d _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1034
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4f5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 388
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519eeff9 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0171b _pthread_wqthread + 290
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0157b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.searchd.application.localization.updates
0   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff51c3ebfd xpc_data_create + 1
1   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff51c4189b xpc_dictionary_set_data + 27
2   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff51c1aff5 _os_activity_stream_entry_encode + 1002
3   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff51c1aa3b _os_activity_stream_reflect + 312
4   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff51c26399 _os_log_impl_stream + 564
5   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff51c2590f _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 6347
6   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff51c24035 _os_log + 162
7   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff51c26923 _os_log_impl + 9
8   com.apple.CoreSpotlight         0x00007fff24f5c4b7 __initEntitlements_block_invoke + 406
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519de7b9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519df9e5 _dispatch_once_callout + 20
11  com.apple.CoreSpotlight         0x00007fff24f5c95a hasInternalCSEntitlement + 40
12  com.apple.CoreServices          0x00007fff24f20014 -[CSSearchableItem setExpirationDate:] + 40
13  com.apple.CoreServices          0x00007fff24f1f0e9 -[CSSearchableItem initWithUniqueIdentifier:domainIdentifier:attributeSet:] + 399
14  searchd                         0x00000001016f17f7 0x101692000 + 391159
15  searchd                         0x00000001016f3720 0x101692000 + 399136
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519dd848 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519de7b9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4526 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4f93 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 443
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519eeff9 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0171b _pthread_wqthread + 290
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0157b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:: Dispatch queue: PKPlugIn start (com.apple.FileProvider.FPSpotlightIndexer)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b56a16 __ulock_wait + 10
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff51bf7c8b _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 160
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff51c46c06 _xpc_uncork_domain + 73
3   com.apple.pluginkit.framework   0x00007fff41ab43b0 0x7fff41ab1000 + 13232
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519dd848 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519de7b9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4526 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4f5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 388
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519eeff9 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0171b _pthread_wqthread + 290
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0157b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 7:: Dispatch queue: Set Attributes scheduler for spindle 0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b55c22 kevent_id + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519fae29 _dispatch_kq_poll + 242
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519faa2e _dispatch_kq_drain + 146
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519fa943 _dispatch_event_loop_drain + 307
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e5d19 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 617
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519eeff9 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0171b _pthread_wqthread + 290
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0157b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b54166 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b546cc mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.mobilespotlight.index 0x00007fff3c9d4e0c _handleExceptions + 114
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c04d36 _pthread_start + 125
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0158f thread_start + 15

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.searchd.workq
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b54166 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b546cc mach_msg + 60
2   libsystem_notify.dylib          0x00007fff51bf15ab notify_check + 290
3   com.apple.CoreServices          0x00007fff24e1e5d4 _LSDatabaseNotificationCheck() + 132
4   com.apple.CoreServices          0x00007fff24e1bf7d _LSDatabaseNeedsUpdate(_LSDatabase*) + 53
5   com.apple.CoreServices          0x00007fff24e1b19d _LSContextInitReturningError + 293
6   com.apple.CoreServices          0x00007fff24e1b8a1 _LSContextInit + 49
7   com.apple.CoreServices          0x00007fff24df3b81 +[LSApplicationProxy applicationProxyForBundleType:identifier:isCompanion:URL:itemID:bundleUnit:] + 201
8   com.apple.CoreServices          0x00007fff24df3f37 +[LSApplicationProxy applicationProxyForIdentifier:] + 32
9   searchd                         0x00000001016dea37 0x101692000 + 313911
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519dd848 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519de7b9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4526 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4f93 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 443
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519eeff9 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0171b _pthread_wqthread + 290
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0157b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:: Dispatch queue: PKPlugIn start (com.apple.eventkitui.spotlight)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b54166 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff51b546cc mach_msg + 60
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff51c4ca35 _xpc_pipe_routine + 348
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff51c4cc04 xpc_pipe_routine_with_flags + 49
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff51c35cc1 _xpc_interface_routine + 169
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff51c46b97 _xpc_bootstrap_services + 115
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff51c46ee3 _xpc_uncork_domain + 806
7   com.apple.pluginkit.framework   0x00007fff41ab43b0 0x7fff41ab1000 + 13232
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519dd848 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519de7b9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4526 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519e4f5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 388
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff519eeff9 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0171b _pthread_wqthread + 290
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0157b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff51c0156c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00000000519df1c0  rbx: 0x00007ff1f1540650  rcx: 0x0000000200000013  rdx: 0x0000000200000013
  rdi: 0x0000000200000010  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000700006fa3450  rsp: 0x0000700006fa3450
   r8: 0x0000003000000000   r9: 0x0060000000000000  r10: 0xfffffff700000000  r11: 0x0000000700000000
  r12: 0x00007ff1f15152c0  r13: 0x00007fff842cf120  r14: 0x0000000200000013  r15: 0x0000000200000002
  rip: 0x00007fff51bf6732  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000010a779a93

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000177
Trap Number:     133
```

```
External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 2345146
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 426

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=588.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=588.9M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=144.6M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=144.6M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Dispatch continuations            12.0M       12 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           110.8M       74 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       12 
Memory Tag 241                      16K        2 
Memory Tag 243                     384K        2 
Memory Tag 244                    3328K        7 
Memory Tag 250                      96K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       19 
Stack                             17.1M       20 
VM_ALLOCATE                        200K        1 
__DATA                            9962K      356 
__DATA_CONST                      39.5M      349 
__DATA_DIRTY                        10K       10 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       290.3M        4 
__OBJC_RO                         42.7M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2128K        1 
__TEXT                           298.6M      359 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
mapped file                      134.7M      147 
shared memory                       24K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.0G     1385
```

[image: Activity Report]

Comment: Forgot to mention that when running Xcode using a physical iPhone device, instead of the simulator, I do not get any crash nor any such similar symptoms (high running fan and very warm machine) .

Comment: I am getting the exact same behavior. Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: I'm seeing this on Mojave, running Xcode 11.2. launchd_sim hits 295% CPU and ReportCrash is hitting 30% or more. MacBook is extremely hot. Seems to have started within the last several days, can't pinpoint what changed.

Comment: I upgraded to Xcode 11.3.1 and haven't experienced the problem since. Coincidence?